# Changing the routing class is throwing an error

Tags: forms, 8, routes

I am trying to change my UserLoginForm class to iLibUserLoginForm with the following code.

```
namespace Drupal\ilib_sso\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
      $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\ilib_sso\Form\iLIBUserLoginForm');
    }
  }

}
```

This is the original yml.

```
user.login:
  path: '/user/login'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm'
    _title: 'Log in'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'FALSE'
  options:
    _maintenance_access: TRUE
```

My iLIBUserLoginForm.php file with the extending class inside it exists at `ilib_sso/src/Form/` but I keep getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Drupal\user\Form\iLIBUserLoginForm, because the name is already in use in /var/www/company/web/modules/custom/ilib_sso/src/Form/iLIBUserLoginForm.php on line 258

Why is it re-declaring this class in `Drupal\user`? How do I prevent that, or modify it so that it works?

All I'm trying to do is extend the login form class with my own custom one.

```
class iLIBUserLoginForm extends UserLoginForm {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "it" involved here.

*You* defined it in the \Drupal\user namespace, as you probably copied the class from user and didn't fix the namespace definition.

Comment: You are absolutely and completely right, and I apologize for wasting your and everyone else's time on this one haha.